# How to format data into a row which in column

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet which need do format the data[image]

I need to format this data like this in different sheet
[image]

Note - This a small sample I created for your understanding

Answer (score 0):

my test macro is below. If you want to use it, you just need to rename your sheets - "DataSheet" for the one with the data and "ResultSheet" where the result will be stored.

```
Sub Reformat()
Dim letter As String
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim rng As Excel.Range

    Sheets("ResultSheet").Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).Value = Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).Value

    Sheets("ResultSheet").Select
    Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)

    For i = 1 To Sheets("DataSheet").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        letter = Sheets("DataSheet").Range("A" & i).Value

        iRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(letter, rng)

        If Range("B" & iRow).Value = "" Then
            Range("B" & iRow).Value = Sheets("DataSheet").Range("B" & i).Value
        Else
            Range("A" & iRow).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value = Sheets("DataSheet").Range("B" & i).Value
        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```